# If stellar bridge goes down, how to retrieve previous transactions?

Tags: bridge-server

Let's say that my Stellar [bridge server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/2-bridge-server.html) is down for a period of time. How do I retrieve all the transactions that come to my address during that time period using stellar bridge?